# How to downcase an entire HTML document parsed with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I need to downcase all text in an HTML document that has been parsed with Nokogiri. Here my code:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get('http://www.example.com').parser.search('//*[translate(text(),"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz") = *]').to_html
```

There is not error as such in the code; it executes without an error. If I go in and check a random tag in the document, however, the case is still the same as before. Is there another/better way to downcase all text in a document?

Comment: Add .downcase next to_html ?

Comment: @daremkd: Nope, doesn't work.

Comment: to_html produces a string and adding downcase next to_html so it's to_html.downcase will make all of that string lowercase. What are you trying to do exactly, do you just try to make the text downcase (between the tags) or make everything downcase, including the tags? Can you include an example?

Comment: I am just trying to downcase all text that is contained between the tags so it will be easier to match it since you don't have to worry about case sensitivity. The tags I don't care about.

Comment: Why don't you return just the text then? use .text instead of .to_html

Comment: I need to keep the original HTML structure intact, so .text is not an option. I thought it should be possible to translate all text in the document to lowercase, but it might actually be a bigger problem than I thought?

Comment: "Easier to match"? Why don't you just use a case insensitive match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`traverse`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node#traverse-instance_method) to downcase all text nodes:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.example.com/"))
doc.traverse do |node|
  node.content = node.content.downcase if node.text?
end

puts doc.to_html
```

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>example domain</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style type="text/css">
    body { ... }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <h1>example domain</h1>
    <p>this domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents. you may use this
    domain in examples without prior coordination or asking for permission.</p>
    <p><a href="http://www.iana.org/domains/example">more information...</a></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```